# LINQ: How to rewrite the WHERE clause in query?

Tags: asp.net, linq, where-clause

My simple one keyword query works as follows:

```
   var query = from product in dc.catalog 
                        where product.Name.Contains("table")
                        select product;
```

I want to provide more flexibility in the query and get keywords from a textbox which can come from a string like "table red round". Here I want the result to have the records that contains ALL of the 3 words (red, round, table) IN ANY ORDER.

How do I rewrite the WHERE clause to handle this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = from product in dc.catalog  
            where textbox1.Text.Split(' ').All(nam => product.Name.Contains(nam)) 
            select product;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this (just noticed you want **all**):

```
var query = from product in dc.catalog 
            where textBox.Text.Split(' ').All(s => product.Name.Contains(s))
            select product;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// You can produce these matches using any method (string.Split, e.g.)
// Just make sure that they're an array or a list.
var matches = new[]{"table", "red", "round"};
var query = from product in dc.catalog 
            where matches.All(m => product.Name.Contains(m))
            select product;
```

Comment: (a) you miss a closing parens (b) that will match any record with _either_ of 'table','red','round', not _all three_. `I want the result to have the records that contains ALL of the 3 words (red, round, table)`

Comment: I can't have seen it because it wasn't there :_ I explicitely refreshed _after_ posting the comment.

Comment: @sehe: I wonder if there was a server-side caching issue. I explicitly refreshed after posting my update, and your comment didn't appear until a couple of minutes later.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `Except` function

e.g.

```
var query = from product in dc.catalog 
                    where !selectedItems.Except(product.Name).Any()
                    select product;
```